# Is it possible to change the default feed widget settings?

Tags: dashboard-widgets

Until you can override widgets on per user group basis, does anyone know if it's possible to change the feed settings to not display the Pixel & Tonic feed in the dashboard and either set it to be blank or another feed? Maybe using a config setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do it on a per-user basis, you can change what feed the widget points to by clicking the dashboard settings icon near the top of the dashboard.  You can also remove the widget entirely from there as well.

The settings for all widgets are json-encoded and saved in the craft_widgets table in the settings column.

Comment: Thanks Brad it was more on a global basis, so that all new users don't see it or see it blank when they first log in. This way every time someone signs up to the site I would need to manually go in a change things before they log in.

Comment: Hi Brad, would I need to send this through support to make it an official feature request or is it enough to ask via SE?

Comment: It's already on our list to revamp how user dashboard widgets work, so this would be included in that.

Comment: Hi All - do we have a timeline on per group settings for the dashboard? It is one major request, and this being added to 2.x or making it a plugin would be perfect. Either this or redirect to Entries to 'miss' the dashboard altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I have just made a plugin to do a similar thing it duplicates a selected users dashboard see https://github.com/james1238/duplicateuserdashboard